# Unable to connect to the machine from Google Cloud console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

After Setting Firewall rules and deny all access to port 22 and allow access to machine public IP and some other IP's . I'm not able to connect to the machine from the console .

Any help will be appreciated .

Thanks

Alon

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you're saying you denied access to port 22 which ssh uses...and are asking how to connect to the machine using ssh (console uses ssh)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in connection from the Cloud Console you'll need to allow (not deny) traffic on TCP port 22 to allow SSH (since as @GabeWeiss mentions the Cloud Console uses SSH).

If you are using the default network there is a [predefined rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#more_rules_default_vpc) to allow ingress connections on TCP port 22 to allow SSH.

The documentation portrays the following [configuration examples](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#configuration_examples) that you might find interesting.

Comment: Thanks . I allowed the ssh connection between the machines in the network .So There is no communication problems between the machines . The problem is that is failed to do ssh from the console itself even If I allow the public IP and also my desktop IP

Comment: If you have enabled a firewall rule similarly as to what is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#DESCRIPTION), the VM itself is not blocking connections to port 22 with the UWF Firewall and you are carefully following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance) to connect from the Cloud Console there shouldn't be any issues.